# Ajax calls on page load increase the onload time

Tags: jquery, web-applications

In my application, I make multiple ajax calls in the `$(document).ready()` function. The problem is that the browser remains in "**loading**" state till the ajax calls have returned. And since these ajax calls take around 15-20 secs to finish, it makes my page load time disgustingly high.
My expectation was that since `ajax` calls are asynchronous, the browser should come out of "loading state" once all page load requests are complete, not caring when ajax calls finish.

Is there some other event after which I should be making the `ajax` calls?
I have also tried to put the `ajax` calls in the `window.onload` event callback, but still I have the same issue.

Edit:
The code is very straightforward. I have an HTML file with a few script tags in the head where I load my scripts:

```
<head>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</head>
```

In one of my scripts I have:

```
$(document).ready( 
     // 3 ajax calls
 );
```

I fetch JSON with the Ajax calls. 
Now, I see in the dev toolkit that the browser comes out of "loading" state only when all of these three ajax calls have returned. 
I have also noticed that when my page load network requests are cached, then browser does not wait for these ajax calls. But with empty cache, it takes around 3-4 secs to complete all page load requests and in this case ajax calls also cause browser to stay in "loading state".

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you try Async Option while you make ajax call. And define callback events?

Comment: Ajax calls are by default Async but if you are not able to still achieve it please define it so.Could you pls show us the page and the code or put it out on Fiddle Pls?

Comment: Try $(window).load() its work after all process is completed

Comment: or try $('selector').ajaxComplete()

Comment: There must be a good reason you're doing them so perhaps look at why the server is taking so long and not so much the front end.

Comment: @popnoodles you are right, the ajax calls need to be optimised at server side. But I am talking about a different problem - browser remaining in loading state  because of ajax calls, when it practically should not, since ajax calls are supposed to be async.

Comment: Are you sure the browser doesn't show loading when you're loading something asynchronously? Are there images or other elements that are taking time to load because you've started some heavy requests?  Have you watched Net on your console to see what's loading?

Comment: I have watched Net in console, and its the ajax calls which cause the browser from coming out of loading state. Ajax calls do not cause browser to enter the loading state. I have other ajax calls which are initiated by user actions, and they do not cause the browser to enter into "loading" state. This problem I am facing is something related to making the ajax requests in $(document).ready(). I need to make them after the browser has finished loading. I dont' see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to load the DOM using AJAX right? Because if there are DOM elements or another web page all together then there is a Problem loading your page since there are multiple pages coming up to build your one page. Because as such as per `$(document).ready()` it seems that you are using JQuery and there is no problem in that and as you have mentioned that you also have callbacks at the same time then the debugging must be kinda ok. If you are trying to do the above the you might face a problem otherwise ajax should not be a pain.

Comment: I am fetching json with the ajax calls.

Comment: @shreyj try calling your JavaScript at the bottom of the file. Add it before the body ends. It would be good for your code.

Answer (score 0):

So far as i know .ready() is a function that executed when the DOM is fully loaded. it mean that "loading" state may not cause by your ajax call. Check if your DOM contains iframe or post your code here.

Comment: I have verified it in the dev toolkit. The loading state is caused by the ajax calls. Actually since these ajax calls take too long, it is very apparent as there is no other network request left other than these ajax calls while browser is still in loading state.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! why don't you call ajax calls in success functions.

```
$.ajax({
.........
    success:function(){
        your load stuff here

       $.ajax({
           .........
           success:function(){
               your load stuff here
           }
      });
    }      // end of success of first ajax call
});
```

or you can use it in the `complete function`:

```
$.ajax({
    .........
    success:function(){
        your load stuff here
    },
    complete:function(){
       $.ajax({
          .........
          success:function(){
               your load stuff here
          },
          complete:function(){

          }
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: or `when()` to perform several ajax queries  and `done()` to do something after they have all finished

Comment: Actually never used these calls.

Comment: You have really because .ajax() uses them. Something about deferreds I sort of half understood at jQcon.

Comment: @Jai won't this just cause the ajax calls to happen one after the other instead of concurrently? I will try this but I don't see how this would prevent browser from waiting for the ajax calls to complete.

Answer (score -3):

Ajax calls are not truly Asynchronous, Ajax helps to make server calls without page postback.

Suppose your calling a Server Side method from JavaScript,
after calling server side method your javaScript will not move to next line untill it receives response from server.

If your using jQuery for Ajax call, make asynch property as true then it wont wait for server response.

Comment: What on earth is a "server side method"?